# AngularJs update class of element

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am pretty new using AngularJS so I can't figure this out. I've got in one part of my application a navigation bar, something like this:

```
<ul class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked'>
    <li class='active'>
       <a>Element 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a>Element 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the same page, I've got a couple of tab pane

```
<div role="tabpanel">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Element 1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">element 1</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#Element 2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">element 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Everything is working as expected, but what I want is the navigation to reflect the status of the tabs, so when the tab 'element 1' is `active`, the navigation item Element 1 get the class `active`.

Is there a simple way to achieve this using angularJS?

I can think a way of doing this by listening to the events triggered by the tabs when they are shown or hidden, but it seems a little complicated, and I was wondering if using Angular this could be done more easily.

BTW, I am using bootstrap 3, if that matters.

Comment: You could consider using angular ui bootstrap. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-class. for example:

```
<li role="presentation" ng-class="{active: activeTab=='HomeTab'}">Home</li>
<li role="presentation" ng-class="{active: activeTab=='ItemsTab'}">Items</li>
```

More examples and details are outlined in here: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-class to set the active class based on a variable that is set when clicking on a tab.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active" ng-class="{'active':isActive(1)}">
      <a>Element 1</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{'active':isActive(2)}">
      <a>Element 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a href="#Element 1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setActive(1)">element 1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a href="#Element 2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setActive(2)">element 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Your controller code would look like this.

```
var activeIndex = 1;

  $scope.isActive = function(index)
  {
    if(index == activeIndex)
    {
      return true
    }
  }
  $scope.setActive = function(index)
  {
    activeIndex = index;
  }
```

Here is a plunk to try it out. http://plnkr.co/edit/KWn4SZ1xUicaorMjM1Fh?p=preview